# PHP not working with wordpress.

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to add php to my form so it submits the information to my email, however the form doesnt seem to be calling the php file correctly.

css

```
<style>

  input[type=text], input[type=number], select[name=province]{ font-family:    arial; width:100%;  
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5; padding: 10px 20px;}
input[name=ffirstname] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=lastname] {width:49%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=address] {width:65.6667%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=unit] {width:32.3337%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=city] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
select[name=province] {width:24%; margin-left:1%;}
input[name=postal] {width:24%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=email] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=phone] {width:49%; margin-left:1%;}

input[class=submit] {

  background-color: #f05a28;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none; !important;
  outline: none; !important ;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none; !important;
```

HTML

```
<form name="infoform" method="post" action="formemail.php" >
```

```
      <br><input type="text" name="ffirstname" placeholder="First Name"/><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
      <br><br><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/><input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="Unit"/></br>
      <br><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"/><select name="province" form="form1">
    <option value="ab">AB</option>
      <option value="BC">BC</option>
      <option value="BC">MB</option>
      <option value="NB">NB</option>
    <option value="NL">NL</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="ON">ON</option>
    <option value="PE">PE</option>
    <option value="QC">QC</option>
    <option value="SK">SK</option>
    </select><input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="Postal Code"/></br>
    <br><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country"/></br>
    <Br><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone#"/></br>
    <br> <br><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Next" />
   </form>
```

The php file is uploaded into the theme folder along with the other php files. But it doesnt seem to be working.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Single Post content template file.
 *
 * @package ThinkUpThemes
 */
?>

<?php
$name = $_POST['ffirstname'];
$email = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['address'];

$to = "arshigtx@hotmail.com"; 
$subject = "My contact form";   
$body = " You have received a new";
mail($to,$subject,$body);
?>
```

Comment: Create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/), and inside place your code (html, php) then just create a page in the backend and pick that page template, and voila, should be working.

Comment: my theme doesnt allow me to make page templates

Comment: What do you mean doesn't allow? Just create a `contact-template.php` with comments on top, and you'll get a template file.

Comment: when i go to create new page in wordpress it doesnt give me the option to select from a list of page templates, will creating this file give me that option?

Comment: Yeah, there are rules in the link I provided what you need to put in the file for it to be recognized as a page template

Comment: Okay thank you, i will give that a try. Why can i not simply upload a php file amongst the other php files and have that called within the form?

Comment: Now that I look at you should be able to. But I have never tried. I usually create a function that will be called when the form is submitted, and in it I'd place the mail function...